# How to show/get some data with an condition in array?

Tags: arrays, laravel-5

> How to show answer where idquestion is 2 using foreach in blade

```
    {"id":1,"answer":"answer1","idquestion":2}
    {"id":2,"answer":"answer2","idquestion":2}
    {"id":3,"answer":"answer3","idquestion":3}
```

> **in controller**

```
$Question= Question::select()->get();
$Answer= Answer::select()->get();
return view('Question.ListQuestion ',compact('Question','Answer'));
```

> **in ListQuestion blade**

```
      @foreach($Question as $question)
            <tr>
               <td>{{$question['thequestion']}}<br>
                   @if($question->menu=="Checkbox")
                        @foreach($Answer as $answer)
                              <input type="checkbox" name=" 
                                 {{$answer['id']}}"value="{{$answer['id']}}">
                                {{$answer['theanswer']}} 
                            <br>
                        @endforeach
                   @endif
                </td>
             </tr>
        @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be wrong, but is this what you are looking for:

```
   @foreach($Answer as $answer)
      @if($answer->idQuestion == 2 )
         <input type="checkbox" name="{{$answer->id}}" value="{{$answer->id}}">
            {{$answer->answer}} 
         <br>
      @endif
    @endforeach
```